# Как правильно связать таблицы pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть две таблицы. Одна в своих ячейках содержит значения, которые нужно заменить значениями из другой таблицы, используя значение ячейки первой как индекс во второй.
Пример первой таблицы:

```
 t1 t2 t3
0 A B C
1 D E F
2 G H I
```

Пример второй таблицы:

```
A x1
B x2
...
I x9
```

Пример таблицы, которая должна получиться:

```
  t1  t2  t3
0 x1 x2 x3
1 x4 x5 x6
2 x7 x8 x9
```

Данные будут не отсортированные и большого объёма. Интересен наиболее быстродейственный способ

Comment: Зря вы удалили данные. Без них непонятна задача. Чтобы нормально показать таблицы в SO - выделите таблицу и нажмите `Ctrl+K`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходные DataFrames:

```
In [38]: d1
Out[38]:
  t1 t2 t3
0  A  B  C
1  D  E  F
2  G  H  I

In [39]: d2
Out[39]:
  c1  c2
0  A  x1
1  B  x2
2  C  x3
3  D  x4
4  E  x5
5  F  x6
6  G  x7
7  H  x8
8  I  x9
```

Решение 1:

```
In [40]: new = d1.replace(d2.set_index('c1')['c2'])

In [41]: new
Out[41]:
   t1  t2  t3
0  x1  x2  x3
1  x4  x5  x6
2  x7  x8  x9
```

Решение 2:

```
In [45]: d1.stack().map(d2.set_index('c1')['c2']).unstack()
Out[45]:
   t1  t2  t3
0  x1  x2  x3
1  x4  x5  x6
2  x7  x8  x9
```